# Quaternion formulation for parallel transport along a curve on a 2-sphere

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, complex-numbers, geodesics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

One image that is often used to illustrate curvature in general relativity is the triangle on a 2-sphere, made out of great circle arcs. At the end of a geodesic transport along this triangle, the transported vector does not coincide with the original one, but is rather rotated by an angle in the tangential plane.

[image]

(image from Wikipedia)

I am interested in that angle if the parallel transport path is not a triangle made of great circle arcs, but an arbitrary path on the 2-sphere. I think I remember that I have once known an expression for parallel transport on a 2-sphere in terms of quaternions, which makes a lot of sense because the sphere is symmetric, while treating parallel transport with the connection in polar coordinates does not explicitly use this symmetry. Hence, parallel transport would look unnecessarily complicated in polar coordinates.

But I can't seem to find this quaternion formulation of parallel transport anymore. I have found some references mentioning the Berry phase, but there seems to be a lot of additional theory around this, which I am not interested in at the moment.

Could somebody point me to a concise treatment of parallel transport with quaternions on a 2-sphere?

Comment: Might any of these help? .
 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333114962_Geometry-Driven_Stochastic_Modeling_of_SE3_States_Based_on_Dual_Quaternion_Representation/figures?lo=1  . http://argos.vu/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/course11.pdf  .                                                     
https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/arnold5.pdf  .  And you've probably seen this one already   .  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329376/is-there-a-close-form-solution-for-parallel-transport-on-2-sphere-along-the-great-circles  .  And thanks for yours re Kaluza-Klein/spin